# How do I find and update the lowest values for a field in a mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am frequently running a mongo db query to find the documents that have the lowest value for a field and then running another query to update them.

For example:

```
    Ticket.find({
    userEvent: eventData._id,
    })
    .sort( { purchasersMinimumPrice: 1 } )
    .then(data => {

    let SecureRefundRequests = data.slice(0, 6).map(e => {return (Ticket.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: e._id}, {
                    refundAttemptExpires :(Date.now() + (5*60*1000))})
                )})

    Promise.all(SecureRefundRequests)
    })
```

To reduce the number of calls to the database I want to do all of this in one query.

I have been playing around with [db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) but can't figure out how to use the index of the returned sorted documents.

Is this possible?

Comment: what is your MongoDB version & what defines a doc has lowest value & another has highest value ?

Comment: I am using db version v4.2.0. I am sorting the query by the field purchasersMinimumPrice. In the above example I want to update the 6 documents with the lowest value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that in a single update command.

`db.collection.update` evaluates each document separately, without keeping any state between documents.  This means you can find the minimum value in an array contained in a document, but you cannot compare a value between documents.

You might improve performance of your existing query by creating an index on 
`{userEvent:1, purchasersMinimumPrice:1, _id:1}` and also apply a limit of 6 on the query, and project for just the _id.  Together these will allow the mongod to find the 6 documents matching that id with the lowest values and return the _id you need to do the update without an in-memory sort, and without actually looking at the documents, i.e. the query is fully covered by the index.